# Overwriting Exception Handlers Provided By Classes

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, oop, exception

I've not been able to find much on this, but I'm also not sure how to search for it, so my apologies if this is a duplicate.

Currently, I have a large amount of code, with occasional mySQL queries throughout. Sometimes, the mySQL connection (which is instantiated on program launch and made accessible to methods that would like to use it, so that new connections aren't constantly made) will fail, for one reason or another. For example, here's an exception that may be raised:
`mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.`

When the exception is raised, I would like the program to try to re-establish the connection to the database, and if that fails, send an alert (via OpsGenie, email, etc). This is pretty trivial and not the part I'm struggling with.

Now, I've thought about how to do this throughout the program, and I know that I can wrap each mySQL query statement in a try...catch..., but I feel that this may be messy and inefficient. I was wondering if there were a way that I could either:

- overwrite the exception handlers in the mySQL package to contain my code to do the above, or
- create somewhat of a "global" try...catch... statement (without actually wrapping the whole program in a try...catch...) that would catch any mySQL connection exceptions and handle them as stated above (perhaps with a method decorator?)

and which would be more efficient or appropriate (if either are).

Insight and thoughts much appreciated.

Note: I am using Python 3 for this project.

## Update

Here's how I solved this issue:

```py
#method
def getNewCursor():
    try:
        return(db.cursor())
    except OperationalError:
        #handle error...

#in practice
cur = getNewCursor()
cur.execute("...the SQL query...")
... etc
```

I did this instead of creating a method to handle the entire query so that I can just get a cursor object and use it how I need, since connection errors are risen when a new cursor is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> overwrite the exception handlers in the mySQL package to contain my code to do the above, or

I wouldn't do that. This might cause side effects on other portions of your code or even 3rd party libraries that you are using/might use.

> create somewhat of a "global" try...catch... statement (

I'd rather do that. This seems to be more maintainable and less error prone.

```py
def run_sql(self, query, retry_times=3):
    try:
        # logic to run the query
    except OperationalError:
        if max_retries:
            send_notification(query)
            raise
        else:
            # logic to run the query again and decrements the max_retries counter
```

Comment: D'oh! Guess I was really overthinking it. This is a great idea, thanks! You raise a good point on overwriting the package exception handlers, I hadn't thought about 3rd party libraries breaking due to that.